# Compose Object of another class in C#

Tags: c#, object, constructor

```
    public class Context
    {
        Strategy strategy;
        // Constructor
        public Context(Strategy strategy)
        {
            this.strategy = strategy;
        }
        public void ContextInterface()
        {
            strategy.AlgorithmInterface();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain this concept?
Why we pass the strategy object in the Context constructor and then assign it to the strategy object again?

Comment: So that it doesn't go out of scope when the constructor ends (thus making it inaccessible to `Context`)? If you're asking a deeper question, you might have to spell it out a bit better since it's not at all obvious.

Comment: `this.strategy` and `strategy` are different variables, which would be more obvious if they had different names.

Comment: Change `Strategy strategy` to `Strategy _strategy` and `this.strategy = strategy;` to `this._strategy = strategy;` and finally `strategy.AlgorithmInterface()` to `_strategy.AlgorithmInterface()` and you'll see what @jeremy is talking about

Comment: @Flydog57 and delete "`this.`" this key code.

Comment: You can delete `this` or not. Or you could add it to `strategy.AlgorithmInterface()` (i.e., `this._strategy.AlgorithmInterface()`)